# How to use class extends List Preference

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a change of features in ListPreference.
So I made a legacy of Kelas from this list, but I don't know how I can use it to change the title of the list, change some color and do some other things.

```
public class ThemedListPreference extends ListPreference implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    public static final String TAG = "ThemedListPreference";

    private int mClickedDialogEntryIndex;

    private CharSequence mDialogTitle;

    public ThemedListPreference(Context context , AttributeSet attrs){

        super(context , attrs);
    }

    public ThemedListPreference(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void setLayoutResource(int layoutResId) {
        super.setLayoutResource(layoutResId);
    }



    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent , View view , int position , long id) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference)

> This class was deprecated in API level 29.

If you want to make changes. You have to return true from your onPreferenceChangeListener.

[PreferenceChangeListener document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.html)

> This interface was deprecated in API level 29.

```
mPreferenceChange.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        .....
        .....
        return true;
    }
});
```